# Is there a way to invoke a component by using HandleClick?

Tags: reactjs

I am facing troubles to make and understand, if its possible, how to call my component  with my react calendar (My calendar is working perfectly when i localhost:3000/Avaibalities).

Here is the code :

Home page of my portfolio :

```
import React from 'react';
import NavigationNew from '../components/NavigationNew';
import Modal from './Modal';

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div className="home">
      <NavigationNew />
      <div className="homeContent">
        <div className="content">
          <h1>Welcome</h1>
          <h2>I'm a Front Desk Agent</h2>
          <a href="./CV.pdf" target="_blank">Download CV</a>
          <Modal />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

`

Here is my component Modal who is called by Home page with a button to invoke my Avaibalities Component with the calendar.

```
import React from 'react';
import Avaibalities from './Avaibalities';


class Modal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    return <Avaibalities />
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Book me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
};


export default Modal;
```

Here is the Avaibalities Component :

```
import React from 'react';
import Calendar from "react-calendar";

class Avaibalities extends React.Component {`enter code here`
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="CalendarMain">
          <h2>My Avaibalities</h2>
          <Calendar />
        </div>
      </>
    )

  }

}

export default Avaibalities;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more straightforward and React friendly way to handle this would be to establish some state that would conditionally display your component.

Here's the kind of modifications you would want to apply:

```
import React from 'react';
import Avaibalities from './Avaibalities';


class Modal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      displayAvailabilities: false,
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.displayAvailabilities && <Availabilities />}
        <button 
          onClick={() => this.setState({ displayAvailabilities: true })}
        >
         Book me
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

This takes advantage of short-circuiting to display the availabilities component when the corresponding state is set to true. You could then hide them again by setting that state to false.

To add on to this, your current approach is certainly returning the component, but nothing is telling React to render the component that is returned from your function.

Comment: No problem, here's some extra reading: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator